# Write unescaped JSON file with Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, continuous-integration, escaping

I'm struggling to figure out how to write a JSON file in ruby without the escaped backslash, I need to produce the following JSON content, so as to match Apple's xctestplan format:

```json
{
   "key": "ClassName\/testSuperImportant()"
}
```

I have the following (simplified) ruby code which results in a double escaped backslash:

```rb
require 'json'

testname = "ClassName.testSuperImportant"

testplan = {
  :key => testname.sub('.', "\\/") + "()"
}

puts JSON.pretty_generate(testplan)
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "key": "ClassName\\/testSuperImportant()"
}
```

Any variation of these `"\/"`, `'\/'` simply produces a single slash like this: `"ClassName/testSuperImportant()"`

I don't have much ruby experience so I'm sure there has to be a clever or easy way to do it. It doesn't have to be done in the JSON stringer it could be by modifying the string afterwards but so far `puts` and `print` preserve the double or non-escaped results which I don't want.

Any help is appreciated, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For some strange reason, JSON *allows* to escape the slash, even though it is not a reserved character. But there is actually *no need* to escape it, since, as I wrote, it is not a reserved character.

So, you can just do

```ruby
require 'json'

testname = 'ClassName.testSuperImportant'

testplan = {
  key: testname.sub('.', '/') + '()'
}

puts JSON.pretty_generate(testplan)
# {
#   "key": "ClassName/testSuperImportant()"
# }
```

Which is actually the same document as yours, just with a different representation.

Comment: Thank you for answering, so basically I need not escape it, I was hoping to match the format as closely as possible. I'll see if there any issues if unescaped.